# errmsg: 'Unsupported projection option: $push: { ... }', code: 2, codeName: 'BadValue' }

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a problem on debugging this error can you help me?

This is my code

```
router.post('/accounts/show_accounts/:id', function(req,res){
    Account.findOne(
        {_id:req.params.id},
        {$push: {team: {team_name: req.body.team_name}}},
        {safe: true, upsert: true},
        function(err, model) {
            console.log(err);
        }
    )
});
```

And I am getting the below error

> errmsg: 'Unsupported projection option: $push: { team: { team_name:
>   “hahaha” } }', code: 2, codeName: 'BadValue' }

Comment: Please post the code and not an image

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As the error states, **[`findOne()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findOne)** method considers the document `{ "$push": { "team": { "team_name": req.body.team_name } } }` as a projection and in a projection field names do not start with `$`. I believe you want to do an update operation, not a query. In that case, you need to use the **[`findOneAndUpdate()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findOneAndUpdate)** or **[`findByIdAndUpdate()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findByIdAndUpdate)** method because the **[`$push`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/push/)** operator is only used in an update operation, not a query like **[`findOne()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findOne)**:

```
router.post('/accounts/show_accounts/:id', function(req, res){
    Account.findByIdAndUpdate(
        req.params.id,
        { "$push": { "team": { "team_name": req.body.team_name } } },
        { "upsert": true, "new": true },
        function(err, model) {
            if (err) throw err;
            console.log(model);
        }
    )
});
```

**NB**: `findByIdAndUpdate(id, ...)` is equivalent to `findOneAndUpdate({ _id: id }, ...)`